# Install a package by launching a new terminal through Python

Tags: python, linux, sudo

I am writing an OS Security Rating Tool which is a GUI software and would check availability of important security components and allow the user to install missing components (e.g. IDS) with a single "install button"

I am using Pycharm as my IDE. I want to install missing software component through GUI for which I am using the following code:

`os.system("sudo apt-get install snort-mysql")`

When a user clicks on "Install" (through the GUI I have created), the above code will be executed and he would be able to follow up with the installation as always.

However, since I am using an IDE, when the install button is clicked, the problem is that I am not able to enter the password as I get the following in the IDE's trace:

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

`Sorry, try again.`

I tried using gksudo and managed to input the password. But I get the following when the installation begins:

`After this operation, 18.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.`

`Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Abort.`

gksudo with force y results in `gksudo: invalid option -- 'y'`

I wanted to know if there is a way to launch a seperate terminal and start with the installation there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gksudo and pass the -y option to **apt-get install** not to gksudo, i.e.

```
os.system('sudo "apt-get install snort-mysql"')
```

or

```
os.system("sudo \"apt-get install snort-mysql\"")
```

You can also use the subprocess.Popen with pipes to allow you to interact with the sub-process(es).

Comment: Is this what you mean?   "gksudo apt-get install -y snort-mysql"                                                               I am still getting the same error. Kindly give an example

Comment: Try: `gksudo "apt-get install -y snort-mysql"`

Comment: Do you mean this: os.system("gksudo" "apt-get install -y snort-mysql")   I'm kind of confused.